# Copy only directories and its contents while excluding outside files using rsync?

Tags: files, directory, rsync

Let's say I have this file structure:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

Is there any way for me to rsync the **directories and its contents** while **excluding the files outside the directories**(1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg)? I have some sort of planned backup thing going on and wanna add a script, make it executable and automate it via crontab, thanks!

Comment: if that files are all `.jpg` files, just use > `rsync -avz --exclude '*.jpg' source/ dest/`

Comment: Yes, but the .jpg files inside the directories are also excluded, it only copies the directories, not the contents within the directories, that was what I tried earlier.

Comment: did you tried `rsync -avz --exclude '/*.jpg' source/ dest/`

Comment: that worked! my parameters were "-avrP" and i saw somewhere that using the z flag takes up unnecessary CPU resources, thank you!

Comment: at first i tried:
rsync -avrP --exclude './*.jpg' ./* /destination/

then:
rsync -avrP --exclude '*.jpg' ./* /destination/

was the issue the recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude only files in top root directory, you have to add starting slash `/`, like:

```
rsync -avz --exclude '/*.jpg' source/ dest/
```

that will exclude all image files only in root and not in any other child directories

[image]